# Find vector which minimises the sum.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, vectors, lagrange-multiplier

Find the vector **r** which minimises the sum *S* = (**r** - a)^2 + (**r** - b)^2 + (**r** - c)^2, where a, b and c are constant vectors.

I'm unsure as to how to go about this. I was thinking it's some sort of constrained optimization, however I'm not well equipped with these tools.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GnKI.png)

Comment: You didn't say what dimension these vectors are, but without loss of generality we can assume they are in $\mathbb R^2$

Comment: Sorry! The dimension weren't given however I think it will be either in R2 or R3

Comment: Also, shouldn't there be some kind of norm somewhere? Or what does it mean to square a vector?

Comment: Please fix the question.

Comment: The question is just as stated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let $r = (r_x,r_y)$ and $a=(a_x,a_y),b=(b_x,b_y),c=(c_x,c_y)$.

Write out the expression $||r-a||^2+ ||r-b||^2 + ||r-c||^2$.

You should get a polynomial with the two variables $r_x$ and $r_y$ that doesn't have mixed terms of the form $r_x^ur_y^v$. Since it doesn't have mixed terms like this you just need to minimize the parts with $r_x$ and the parts with $r_y$ which is easy as these are just degree $2$ polynomials in one variable.

We now solve the subproblem of minimizing $(r-a)^2 + (r-b)^2 + (r-c)^2 = 3r^2-2(a+b+c)r + a^2+b^2+c^2$.

Taking derivative we have $6r-(a+b+c) = 0$ and so we take $r=(a+b+c)/3$

So the point we want is the incenter of the points $a,b,c$ which is given by the expression $(\frac{a_x+b_x+c_x}{3},\frac{a_y+b_y+c_y}{3})$

Comment: I think this makes sense! Thanks!

Comment: nevermind I think I made a mistake

Comment: Once you make the general expression, use of calculus should be enough right? Perhaps a partial differential?

Comment: yes I believe so.

Answer (score 1):

Cancelling the gradient,

$$\nabla S=2(r-a)+2(r-b)+2(r-c)=0$$

we get

$$r=\frac{a+b+c}3.$$

Comment: Oh this seems like the correct way of doing it especially given the way the problem is written